# Who and what is Karla?

Tags: tinker-tailor-soldier-spy

Throughout the movie, several characters, including Smiley, refer to a person named Karla.  I assume it's a code name for a person, but I am still confused as to who it specifically refers to, and what their importance to the plot is.

So, who is Karla?

Comment: It is clear in both the books and all the adaptations that "Karla" is a real individual and currently high up in Soviet intelligence. In both the movie and TV series, Smiley recounts meeting him in person in India long before he became a senior spook.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's never stated what his real name is or his official title or position in the Russian intelligence apparatus.

> Karla is a fictional character in several novels by John le Carré. A Soviet Intelligence officer, he most often appears as a distant antagonist of George Smiley. His real name is never revealed; **instead he takes his codename from that of the first network that he recruited**.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karla_(character))</sup>

As for his importance to the plot of *Tinker, Tailor*..

> Karla is first mentioned in Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy as **the spymaster who recruited and controls "Gerald", the mysterious mole inside the Circus**. By the time of that novel, Gerald has become Circus' number-two-man and Karla is using Gerald's handler, Alexei Polyakov, to deliver fabricated intelligence that appears highly valuable.

---

> Karla appears briefly in the BBC adaptations of Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy and Smiley's People, though he does not speak in either. He is played by Patrick Stewart.
>
> Karla appears briefly in the 2011 film adaptation of Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy as a voice, provided by Michael Sarne, as well as in a partial shot in a Budapest coffee shop holding Smiley's lighter.

[image]